# Change text in dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, dom

I have a bunch of textboxes that are created dynamically one per click.
They all have the same name "discount[]", same id "discount" and have the same class "tinput".

Is there anyway that I can use to change the text in all of these textboxes with javascript or jquery?

I have another bunch of the dynamically created text boxes.
The id and name are unique but the class remains the same.
If it gets the job done, I can change the class name.

Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: not sure but `this` can be useful. Id should always be different.

Comment: Show how you're creating these elements, because the duplicate `id` invalidates your HTML; needlessly, when it's easy to alter the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't use an id more than once per document. If you need it for a `<label>` you might want to consider putting the input in the `<label>`.

You are using the `class` attribute the right way, though. You can do:

```
$('.tinput').val('New value for all .tinputs!');
```

If you can't put the input inside the label you can use use this. I made this demo for someone a little while ago. It might be helpful. It'll increment an id like "id-1".

http://jsbin.com/APegOMo/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: A lot of accessibility experts do not like form elements to be descendants of the label element, so a unique Id is required.

Edit: I actually created a utility to solve this issue [https://github.com/Jshthornton/lid.js](https://github.com/Jshthornton/lid.js)

Comment: Interesting... Any links to back that up? I try to keep up but never came across that claim. I've heard complaints about just using labels inside inputs visually.

Comment: @BillCriswell No links, but I work with several accessibility agencies, they get a sketchy with inputs in labels. Even though W3C say it is valid some screenreaders just don't comply.

Comment: If you ever come across a reason why they get sketchy about it I'd like to hear it. The <label> tag has been around for more than 10 years at this point and this usage is really common.

Answer (score 0):

> same id "discount"

Please, don't do that! "id" is to identify a dom element. That hurts in my soul.
If every id is unique you could access them by $("#myid").val("my new val"). Just an example.

Regards, - Tobbo

Comment: "hurts my soul" -- glad Im not the only one.  I cringe when I see this online and usually just back away slowly instead of trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example that takes all elements with a particular class name and changes the .html, not 100% sure I understand what you're after though.   if you need to do someting specific with each divs text you can iterate through them by id (and maybe class as well) and change each divs individual .html.

if you can share a stripped down example of your code or elaborate I'd love to try to help.  good luck.

```
$(".changeDivs").html("adfasdf");
```

[jsfiddle example >>](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/JKL26/)